# Endnotes doesn't call counter correctly

Tags: macros, counters, endnotes

I am trying to send numbered observations to the last page, as shown in the following MWE. How can I obtain the correct numbers to be displayed at the last page? Thank you!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{endnotes}

\newcounter{thought}

\def\mythought{%
    \refstepcounter{thought}
    \noindent
    \textbf{Thought \#\thethought:}
    }

%-> Defining the environment for the OBSERVATIONS @ the footnote
\newcommand{\myfnobs}[1]{%
    \let\thefootnote\relax %... suppresses the footnote numbering
    \footnote{\textbf{Observation on thought \#\thethought-} #1}
    }


%-> Redefine the ENDOTES page title:
\renewcommand{\notesname}{My observations}

%-> Defining the environment for the OBSERVATIONS @ last page
\newcommand{\mylpobs}[1]{%
    \let\theendnote\relax %... suppresses the \endnote numbering
    \endnote{\textbf{Observation on thought \#\thethought-} #1}
    }


\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
    In this MWE I show that the \texttt{endnotes} package doesn't read each \texttt{thought} counter value, but only the last one.
\end{abstract}


\section{Introduction}
The \texttt{endnotes} package is based on the \texttt{\textbackslash footnote} command. The difference: it sends the content to the last page. I created two commands in the preable, as described below

\begin{itemize}
    \item \texttt{\textbackslash myfnobs}, which receives one argument, is the command that places my observations in the footnote of the page where it occurs.

    \item \texttt{\textbackslash mylpobs}, which receives one arguement, is the command that places my observation in the last page of the document.
\end{itemize}

I also defined the macro \texttt{\textbackslash mythought}, where I want to express my thoughts. This is numbered sequentially. For examples, see next section.




\section{Thoughts placed at the footnote}
I want to express three thoughts of mine.

\mythought
Everyday is a good day to start something new in our lives.%
    \myfnobs{This may not be true if we still didn't accomplish what we started last.}

\mythought
It is never late to learn new things.%
    \myfnobs{I believe this has no exception}

\mythought
Tolerance is the key to achieve better world.%
    \myfnobs{Intolerance causes violence, war, and death.}




\section{Thoughts placed at the last page}
Please, let me repeat my three thoughts, but changing the command from \texttt{\textbackslash myfnobs} to \texttt{\textbackslash mylpobs}:

\mythought
Everyday is a good day to start something new in our lives.%
    \mylpobs{This may not be true if we still didn't accomplish what we started last.}

\mythought
It is never late to learn new things.%
    \mylpobs{I believe this has no exception}

\mythought
Tolerance is the key to achieve better world.%
    \mylpobs{Intolerance causes violence, war, and death.}




\section{Final considerations}
Let's finish this issue by adding new page and calling the \texttt{\textbackslash theendnotes} command. Observe that at such page, all the \textbf{Observation on thought \#} receive the value 6 (six), instead of the intended value, differently from what happened to when I called the \texttt{\textbackslash myfnobs}


\newpage
\theendnotes



\end{document}
```

**First page output:**
[image]

**Last page output:**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to expand `\thethought`: the footnote text is expanded right away, so there is no problem with it, but `\endnote` just saves the text without interpreting it.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{endnotes}

\newcounter{thought}

\newcommand\mythought{%
  \refstepcounter{thought}%
  \noindent
  \textbf{Thought \#\thethought:}%
}

%-> Defining the environment for the OBSERVATIONS @ the footnote
\newcommand{\myfnobs}[1]{%
  \let\thefootnote\relax %... suppresses the footnote numbering
  \footnote{\textbf{Observation on thought \#\thethought-} #1}
}


%-> Redefine the ENDOTES page title:
\renewcommand{\notesname}{My observations}

%-> Defining the environment for the OBSERVATIONS @ last page
\newcommand{\mylpobs}[1]{%
  \let\theendnote\relax %... suppresses the \endnote numbering
  \begingroup
  \edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\endnote{\noexpand\textbf{Observation on thought \noexpand\#\thethought-} \unexpanded{#1}}%
  }\x
}


\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
    In this MWE I show that the \texttt{endnotes} package doesn't read each \texttt{thought} counter value, but only the last one.
\end{abstract}


\section{Introduction}
The \texttt{endnotes} package is based on the \texttt{\textbackslash footnote} command. The difference: it sends the content to the last page. I created two commands in the preable, as described below

\begin{itemize}
    \item \texttt{\textbackslash myfnobs}, which receives one argument, is the command that places my observations in the footnote of the page where it occurs.

    \item \texttt{\textbackslash mylpobs}, which receives one arguement, is the command that places my observation in the last page of the document.
\end{itemize}

I also defined the macro \texttt{\textbackslash mythought}, where I want to express my thoughts. This is numbered sequentially. For examples, see next section.




\section{Thoughts placed at the footnote}
I want to express three thoughts of mine.

\mythought
Everyday is a good day to start something new in our lives.%
    \myfnobs{This may not be true if we still didn't accomplish what we started last.}

\mythought
It is never late to learn new things.%
    \myfnobs{I believe this has no exception}

\mythought
Tolerance is the key to achieve better world.%
    \myfnobs{Intolerance causes violence, war, and death.}




\section{Thoughts placed at the last page}
Please, let me repeat my three thoughts, but changing the command from \texttt{\textbackslash myfnobs} to \texttt{\textbackslash mylpobs}:

\mythought
Everyday is a good day to start something new in our lives.%
    \mylpobs{This may not be true if we still didn't accomplish what we started last.}

\mythought
It is never late to learn new things.%
    \mylpobs{I believe this has no exception}

\mythought
Tolerance is the key to achieve better world.%
    \mylpobs{Intolerance causes violence, war, and death.}




\section{Final considerations}
Let's finish this issue by adding new page and calling the \texttt{\textbackslash theendnotes} command. Observe that at such page, all the \textbf{Observation on thought \#} receive the value 6 (six), instead of the intended value, differently from what happened to when I called the \texttt{\textbackslash myfnobs}


\newpage
\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, it's useless to repeat `\let\thefootnote\relax`, unless you hide it inside a group. The first call to `\myfnobs` will set `\thefootnote` to `\relax` *globally*. Similarly for `\theendnote`.